# jmeter post request type automatically gets changed in sampler view

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to test post api with request type application/json. but somehow in my output it gives me `Content-Type` as `text/html`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You receive 301 error code so maybe your url is wrong see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

Comment: can you show response?